# Customise(Pivot) display of a Jqgrid with a Nested JSON object

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JSON

```
{"empId":"4444","skill":{"rating":"1","review":"Great"},"productivity":{"rating":"2","review":"Good"}};
```

Here is my colModel of the jqgrid code as of now.

```
colModel: [
{name:'skill.rating',label:'Skill Rating', width:150,editable: true},
{name:'skill.review',label:'Skill Review', width:150,editable: true},
{name:'productivity.rating',label:'Productivity Rating',width:150,editable: true},
{name:'productivity.review',label:'Productivity Review', width:150,editable: true}]
```

And this is how my grid looks like now 
[image: My JqGrid]

But this grid design makes it hard for future scaling, in case there is a new category Reliability review and rating then the grid design has to be changed manually.

Instead i want to make it look in this format in the grid

```
Category      ||  Rating   || Review
----------------------------------
Skill         ||  1        || Great
Productivity  ||  2        || Good
Reliability   ||  3        || Average
```

**Is there a way to do this with Jqgrid without having to change the structure of the JSON object(as I have no control on the object, i only fetch it through a service)??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to manipulate the jsonReader (which can be a function)  rather than to change the colModel. See the [Guriddo docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#jsonreader-as-function) for detailed explanation

Try with the following code:

```
colModel: [
    {name:'category',label:'Category', width:150,editable: true},
    {name:'rating',label:'Skill Rating', width:150,editable: true},
    {name:'review',label:'Skill Review', width:150,editable: true}
],
jsonReader : {
    root : function (data) {
        var ret  = [];
        for( var key in data) {
            if($.isPlainObject(data[key])) {
                var tmp = data[key];
                tmp.category = key;
                ret.push(tmp);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
},
```

**UPDATE**

Below the working code

**HTML**

```
<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var mydata ={"empId" : "4444", "skill" : "rating":"1", "review":"Great"}, "productivity" : {"rating":"2","review":"Good"}, "reliability" : {"rating":"3","review":"Very Good"}};


        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datastr : mydata,
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            colModel: [
                {name:'category',label:'Category', width:150,editable: true},
                {name:'rating',label:'Skill Rating', width:150,editable: true},
                {name:'review',label:'Skill Review', width:150,editable: true}
            ],
            jsonReader : {
                root : function (data) {
                    var ret  = [];
                    for( var key in data) {
                        if($.isPlainObject(data[key])) {
                            var tmp = data[key];
                            tmp.category = key;
                            ret.push(tmp);
                        }
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 780,
            rowNum: 15,
            //cellEdit : true,
            rownumbers: true, // show row numbers
            rownumWidth: 25, // the width of the row numbers columns
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
```

Here the link to [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/guriddo/84tbrzus/9/)
datatype is jsonstring, but it it the same as json. This set is mainly for jsfiddle to work.

Comment: It isn't working, I get an empty grid. However thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What is your datatype local or json?  At our  end this works fine. I will prepare a demo. By the way , which version of jqGrid is used?